# Php spacing within the code

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
<?php wpfp_link();the_views(); ?>
```

On running, it shows:

Add to favorites. Views:6

I want it to show like below, with spaces.

```
Add to favorites.                                         Views: 6
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You _really_ should be doing layout-ey stuff like this in CSS.

Comment: @JamWaffles WordPress encourages doing all sorts of things the wrong way.

Comment: You don't want to "space within PHP code", you want to **style the output**. Which is what properly structured HTML and CSS are for.

Comment: JamW, they are just functions of outside of site using wordpress plugins.

Comment: @GurpreetSingh just use **inline css**, i think this is a basic thing which if you didn't know, you could google it ...

Comment: I'm sorry if you can't take criticism, but the voting system on Stackoverflow is indeed designed to promote good questions and push down questions which are generally not useful to other users, since they're too localized, badly phrased, show no research effort, are too trivial and similar things. It does not revolve around *you*.

Comment: Deceze, this site has become a place for self centered and egoistic people, who just think they want to develop new facebook,or expect others to ask things of that level. Man, everyone has to start from somewhere, think about yourself when you started.

Comment: While I am perfectly sympathetic to that point of view... when I started, there was no Stackoverflow. When I started, when I came across a problem, I either had to read a manual, or a tutorial, or a book, or randomly Google search the interweb to come up with some clues as to what's going on. And *that* I think still is the foundation of the profession of programming. Just throwing any sort of trivial question onto Stackoverflow does not help you develop researching skills, which are essential. It also clutters Stackoverflow, making it harder to find answers to *really* complicated questions.

Comment: Does stackoverflow pays you, that you care so much about all this???, I see ppl's thinking have downgraded, who just argue over answering a small question,,its not only you but many,, check out all the answers of this question for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php wpfp_link(): ?> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; blah blah blah <?php the_views(); ?>
```

Comment: It's the correct answer, but the wrong solution to a problem that the OP doesn't understand I think.

Comment: the proper solution, of course, is to ditch wordpress. it's a cancer on the world.

Comment: Upvoting to remove the downvote (this may be ugly but it is the correct answer) :-) Unless of course he uses HTML and CSS

Comment: Thanks Marc B. 
Sorry but what if I have to enter multiple &nbsp; in code?

Comment: who uses &nbsp; to spacing things anymore?

Comment: @Extelliqent  in tables to fill the empty cells.

Comment: I love the solution. It does what is asked. It's good enough for a one time fix.

Comment: @Grumpy you can fill those tables by display:block;width:10px;height:10px;. you don't need to put &nbsp; there ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "Add to favorites. Views: 6" you want "Add to favorites". Then you would have to take the_views(); out and since wpfp_link(); puts Add to favorites on the page you would have to get in wpfp_link(); and add  before "Add" and  after "Add". it would make Add portion of the text blue.

If you want to give it a space after wpfp_link(); basically wrap it with a span and give it a margin/padding right, that is the best way of doing that.

Like this;

```
<?php 
       echo "<span style='color:blue;padding-right:10px'>";
             wpfp_link();
       echo "</span>";
             the_views();
 ?>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ygkFc/

Comment: don't hate okay.. Tell me why it's not a solution? it puts the spacing and colors the first php value. If he wants to color only "add" he has to find where the value being set for wpfp_link(); and give it a blue color there.

Comment: `the_views();` will not move right and stays near `wpfp_link()`.

Comment: look at the code before you make the comment @MuthuKumaran ;) give it a shot on your browser if you can't imagine how it works; http://jsfiddle.net/ygkFc/

Comment: you think `padding-right:10px` will be enough? It's not dynamic and OP have adjust each time when he needs to spacing.

Comment: when the width is on auto it will adjust it's width itself and it will give 20px padding to it. Your solution makes the spacing 200-300px Muthu, do you think it's the way to do ? Please ! if 10px is not enough make it 30px doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some HTML and CSS,

```
<span><?php wpfp_link(); ?></span> <span style="float:right"><?php the_views(); ?></span>
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/E4y7y/1/

**Solution 2**

```
<span style="display:inline-block;width:60%"><?php wpfp_link(); ?></span> <span  style="display:inline-block;width:35%;" ><?php the_views(); ?></span>
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/E4y7y/

Comment: you float the second element to the right without knowing how far right it can go.. Is that the solution ? if the page 800px the second php value will be written 600px away from the add the favorites, if the page 300px wide then it'll be written 100px away..

Comment: @Extelliqent OP has to decide on that. There are many ways we can do this. Lets leave it with OP.

Comment: floating second element to the right is not a way. It is a wrong solution. Just think about it. I am not saying it is a solution, but a bad one. I am saying it is not a solution. You floating the second element to the right without knowing how far right it can go? Does it make sense ?

Comment: <div style="width:100px"><span><?php wpfp_link(); ?></span> <span style="float:right"><?php the_views(); ?></span></div> If you make something I can understand, but it would be still not good since we don't know how big the area will be taken by the php code. if there are 1000 views there would be less spacing than if there is only 1 view. Do you understand my point ?

Comment: Thanks Muthu, others are waste here!

Comment: @Extelliqent I told you there are many ways to do. I added second method and you can see it yourself, http://jsfiddle.net/E4y7y/. Also updated my answer.

Comment: @MuthuKumaran as you see in your jsfiddle.net example there is enourmously big spacing between the first and second element. Who would want that much spacing ? http://jsfiddle.net/ygkFc/ Do you see how much less code I am using here ? Why would I do samething by writing more code ? Use your html+css more efficiently.

Comment: There is no argument, I am just saying his solutions are neither efficient nor problem-free ;) you will always have a problem when you give it a fluid size without any reason ;)

Answer (score 0):

Its purely a CSS thing.It depends upon the DOM where are you trying to show the out put..
You can put them in separate DOM and apply margin or float and display as like you want..

```
<div style = "float:left"><?php wpfp_link();?></div>
<div style = "float:right"><?php the_views(); ?></div>
```